# postgresql - Join tables on match but also ones that are not matching?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

So I have a join and it works but its not showing me all the data I want.  Currently I want to see every line in `device_interface.c1` and if `device_interface.c1 = device_inventory.c1` then I want to see that in a column as well.  Right now I am only seeing what `device_interface.c1 = device_inventory.c1`.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT 
  device_info.pk,
  device_interface.fk, 
  device_interface.c1, 
  device_interface.c2, 
  device_inventory.c1
FROM 
  "test".device_info, 
  "test".device_interface, 
  "test".device_inventory
WHERE 
  device_info.pk = device_interface.fk AND
  device_info.pk = device_inventory.fk AND
  device_interface.c1 = device_inventory.c1 AND
  device_interface.c2 = 'Physical'
```

Example Output:

```
device_info.pk  device_interface.c1   device_inventory.c1
1                        1                     1
1                        3                     3
1                        95                    95
2                        55                    55
2                        634                   634
```

Example of desired output:

```
device_info.pk  device_interface.c1   device_inventory.c1
1                        1                     1
1                        2          
1                        3                     3
1                        4
1                        5
1                        6
1                        95                    95
2                        55                    55
2                        56 
2                        57
2                        634                   634
```

Comment: What you're looking for is a left join. Sorry I don't have time for an answer, but have a look at this article about [Visual Representation Of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33052/visual-representation-of-sql-joins).

Comment: Thank you I will read this over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `left join` should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
  device_info.pk,
  device_interface.fk, 
  device_interface.c1, 
  device_interface.c2, 
  device_inventory.c1
FROM 
  "test".device_info
LEFT JOIN
  "test".device_interface 
ON 
  device_info.pk = device_interface.fk
LEFT JOIN
  "test".device_inventory 
ON 
  device_info.pk = device_inventory.fk AND
  device_interface.c1 = device_inventory.c1
WHERE 
  device_interface.c2 = 'Physical'
```

Comment: Thanks guys Im new at this and this will help alot!!